# Cannot check DataGridView row selected or not when form load C#

Tags: c#, datagridview

I want to check DataGridView row selected or not when Form load to do some stuff but it did not work for me when using this code:

```
 private void btnEdit_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            if (grdInvoiceDetails2.Rows.Count > 0 && grdInvoiceDetails2.SelectedRows.Count > 0)
            {
                try
                {
                    Them = false;
                    var r = grdInvoiceDetails2.CurrentCell.RowIndex;
                    txtQty.Text = grdInvoiceDetails2.Rows[r].Cells[3].Value.ToString();
                    cboInvNo.SelectedValue = grdInvoiceDetails2.Rows[r].Cells[1].Value.ToString();
                    cboItemName.SelectedValue = grdInvoiceDetails2.Rows[r].Cells[2].Value.ToString();
                    cboItemName.Enabled = true;
                    cboInvNo.Enabled = false;
                    txtQty.Enabled = true;

                    btnSave.Enabled = true;
                    btnCancel.Enabled = true;
                    btnAdd.Enabled = false;
                    btnEdit.Enabled = false;
                    btnDelete.Enabled = false;
                    btnBack.Enabled = false;
                    LoadDataToCollection();


                }
                catch (Exception ex)
                {
                    MessageBox.Show(ex.ToString());
                }
            }

        }
```

When debugging, grdInvoiceDetails2.Rows.Count=6, grdInvoiceDetails2.SelectedRows.Count=1
But If I did not click on any row, it will throw an exception .Because grdInvoiceDetails2.CurrentCell= null.

Comment: You must check if(grdInvoiceDetails2.SelectedRows.Count > 0) then you can call grdInvoiceDetails2.CurrentCell, otherwise you see null, result is exception. During Form_Load, there are no SelectedRows. It happens only if you click on the row or set the SelectedRow. But that happens long after Form_Load

Answer (score 0):

[`Form.Load`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.form.load(v=vs.110).aspx) event occurs before a form is displayed for the first time, all initialization happens that time. It is *not* advisable to place `DataGridView` specific logic inside `Load` event (Most controls still may be initializing).

I would suggest subscribe to [`DataGridView.DataBindingComplete`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.datagridview.databindingcomplete(v=vs.110).aspx) and play with your logic.

```
dataGridView1.DataBindingComplete += dataGridView1_DataBindingComplete;

private void dataGridView1_DataBindingComplete(object sender,
    DataGridViewBindingCompleteEventArgs e)
{
    // logic here.
}
```

Comment: I could not find DataBindingComplete event. Where is it? I'm using .NET 4.5

Comment: Did you check this [link](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.datagridview.databindingcomplete(v=vs.110).aspx)?

Comment: I see, but I cannot use this code when I click Edit button to load data from DataGridView row to form. I just want to check if user did not click any DataGridView row do nothing else load data to form.

Comment: You mentioned _"I want to check DataGridView row selected or not when Form load to do some stuff "_ so I though you want to place some logic, if you are just looking for logic to check rows are selected or not when you click edit button, just use `if( grdInvoiceDetails2.SelectedRows != null && grdInvoiceDetails2.SelectedRows.Count > 0)`

Comment: When I change the code as your suggestion, it did not work , nothing happen.  private void btnEdit_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            if (grdInvoiceDetails2.SelectedRows != null && grdInvoiceDetails2.SelectedRows.Count > 0) 
            {
                //some stuff
            }
           
        } . Because grdInvoiceDetails2.SelectedRows != null is always return true